# Golang - Github Mux, context.go -> No such file or directory

Tags: go, mux

I want to install the Mux package with (`go get github.com/gorilla/mux`) but I always get the errormessage

```
# github.com/gorilla/context
open go/src/github.com/gorilla/context/context.go: No such file or directory
```

I have created the directories github.com, gorilla and context on my own. But I have no context.go file.... how can I fix it?

Comment: I made the same mistake over the weekend. Once $GOPATH is set you shouldn't create any of the package directories yourself. Go does it for you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just install it with `go get`:

```
$ go get github.com/gorilla/context
$ cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/gorilla/context/
~/go/src/github.com/gorilla/context$ ls
context.go  context_test.go  doc.go  LICENSE  README.md
```